# Quartz.NET, "Error communicating with remote scheduler."

Tags: .net, quartz.net

I'm having trouble getting a client/server implementation of Quartz.NET working.

I have a SQL Server on ServerA, a server running Quartz as a service (ServerB) and a server which hosts an ASP.NET application (ServerC).

I have followed all the tutorials and delved into the code a fair amount but I can't see what I'm doing wrong. The server is definitely listening and I can see the port is open from ServerC. No firewalls involved.

ServerB, which is running the service included in the download package (Quartz.Server.Service) has the following config file settings:

```
<quartz>
    <add key="quartz.server.serviceName" value="quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.server.serviceDisplayName" value="Job Scheduler" />
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="RemoteServer" />
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="10" />
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadPriority" value="Normal" />
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.exporter.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.RemotingSchedulerExporter, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.exporter.port" value="5656" />
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.exporter.bindName" value="QuartzScheduler" />
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.exporter.channelType" value="tcp" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix" value="qrtz_" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.dataSource" value="db" />
    <add key="quartz.dataSource.db.provider" value="SqlServer-20" />
    <add key="quartz.dataSource.db.connectionString" value="Data Source=ServerA;Initial Catalog=dev;User ID=dev;Password=dev" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.useProperties" value="true" />
    <add key="quartz.jobStore.lockHandler.type" value="Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.UpdateLockRowSemaphore, Quartz" />
</quartz>
```

The ASP.NET app has the following config:

```
<quartz>
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="RemoteClient" />
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" />
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="5" />
    <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadPriority" value="Normal" />
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.proxy" value="true" />
    <add key="quartz.scheduler.proxy.address" value="tcp://ServerB:5656/QuartzScheduler" />
</quartz>
```

I have tried numerous things. Occasionally I get an error that the scheduler already exists instead of the one in the question title.

I have read elsewhere that due to threading issues I should create the scheduler in a singleton, which I have done:

```
    private static readonly ISchedulerFactory _schedulerFactory;
    private static readonly IScheduler _scheduler;

    static JobScheduleService() {
        _schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        _scheduler = _schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
    }

    public static IScheduler GetScheduler() {
        return _scheduler;
    }
```

What have I missed? TIA

---

If I open up a telnet box on the web server and connect to the quartz server then the service is definitely responding. If I type a few characters I get an error from Quartz.

Does this help? I.e. it's not a connectivity issue?

[image: Telnet]

Comment: Was the dll file missing on quartz service or on the app from where you were remotely connecting? Would you mind sharing the dll name? I am having the same issue while remotely connecting to a quartz server.

Comment: It was on the server, but I don't recall which dll it was - it would have been Quartz.Core.dll, Quartz.Service.dll, or the assembly in which I had implemented my IJob interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the error message is just a bit misleading. The error wasn't in the communication with the server at all. The problem was a missing DLL file that wasn't being copied as part of the deployment. The underlying error was due to the schedulers inability to find the DLL.

Comment: To add to this, I've found this error also happens when trying to add a job that references a class not found by the quartz.net server.

Comment: Would have loved to have know what dll it was. I am having this issue now.

Comment: It was the DLL where I had created the IJob implementations, not anything to do with the Quartz DLLs themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Try NOT setting any of the quartz.threadpool.xxxxxx properties.

Comment: I commented them out on the quartz server and restarted the service, then on the web server. I still get the same error.

Comment: I should have been more specific... comment them out only on the client side. It might not help, but this is the only difference I see in what we're doing and what you're doing.

Comment: Nothing really. I'm assuming you've already tried connecting to the port from the server with the asp.net application using the same user, just to exclude connectivity and permissions.

Comment: The service is running under the local system account, do you have a different configuration?

Comment: Yes, we run the service using a domain account and we do the same for the web application.

Comment: Have you seen any documentation that states this as a requirement? I've looked around and can't find any. Our servers are not on a domain.

Comment: I haven't seen anything in the documentation, it's just how we have them set up.

Comment: I now have this working. I have not had to use domain accounts. I have removed the threadpool properties on the client side, but it was not the source of the problem. I've posted a separate response with the solution in my case. Thanks for your help.